# How to import 2 instances of a python module from different folders?

Tags: python, flask

I have a python project with the following folder structure:

```
P1
  v1
  v2
  app.py

P2
  v1
  v2
```

Here P1 and P2 are 2 independent python code bases with multiple files internally. The naming and structure of v1 and v2 in P2 are identical. My P1 code base is a flask application and v1 and v2 of P1 use v1 and v2 of P2 respectively. But when I run the flask app I've noticed that the v1 and v2 of P1 use the version from P2 which was initialised first. How can I solve this problem and make sure each of the versions use the separate code versions respectively.

P.S. I'm importing a class from P2 in P1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
import P1.v1 as p1v1
import P1.v2 as p1v2
import P2.v1 as p2v1
import P2.v2 as p2v2
```

?